# Best practice to collect information from child objects

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns, object-oriented

I'm regularly facing following pattern:

```
public abstract class BaseItem
{
    BaseItem[] children;

    // ...

    public void DoSomethingWithStuff()
    {
        StuffCollection collection = new StuffCollection();
        foreach(child c : children) c.AddRequiredStuff(collection);
        // do something with the collection ...
    }

    public abstract void AddRequiredStuff(StuffCollection collection);
}

public class ConcreteItem : BaseItem
{
    // ...

    public override void AddRequiredStuff(StuffCollection collection)
    {
        Stuff stuff;
        // ...
        collection.Add(stuff);
    }
}
```

Where I would prefer something like this, for better information hiding:

```
public abstract class BaseItem
{
    BaseItem[] children;

    // ...

    public void DoSomethingWithStuff()
    {
        StuffCollection collection = new StuffCollection();
        foreach(child c : children) collection.AddRange(c.RequiredStuff());
        // do something with the collection ...
    }

    public abstract StuffCollection RequiredStuff();
}

public class ConcreteItem : BaseItem
{
    // ...

    public override StuffCollection RequiredStuff()
    {
        StuffCollection stuffCollection;

        Stuff stuff;
        // ...
        stuffCollection.Add(stuff);

        return stuffCollection;
    }
}
```

What are pros and cons of each solution?

For me, giving the implementation access to parent's information is some how disconcerting. On the other hand, initializing a new list, just to collect the items is a useless overhead ...

What is the better design? How would it change, if `DoSomethingWithStuff` wouldn't be part of `BaseItem` but a third class?

PS: there might be missing semicolons, or typos; sorry for that! The above code is not meant to be executed, but just for illustration.

Comment: Did you profile the code to know that the overhead is a problem?

Comment: Not yet. I assume it's not a real issue - at least if cardinality of children is reasonable small. But for me it's about best practice / pros and cons ... the size of children might, however, be a sensible basis of decision-making.

Comment: Why are you using `StuffCollection` instead of some generic collection, like `List<Stuff>`?

Comment: @svick: no special reason. I'm working on a SharePoint project and nearly everything is encapsulated in a special collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> initializing a new list, just to collect the items is a useless overhead

instantiate 2 class-level collections, once. The first is for the cumulative `AddStuff()` and the other is to pass to the child - and is reused.

```
public abstract class BaseItem
{
    BaseItem[] children;
    StuffCollection masterCollection;
    StuffCollection transferCollection;

    // ...

    public void DoSomethingWithStuff()
    {
        masterCollection = masterCollection?? new StuffCollection();
        transferCollection = transferCollection?? new StuffCollection();

        transferCollection.Clear();

        foreach(child c : children) {
            c.RequiredStuff(transferCollection);
            masterCollection.AddRange(transferCollection);
            transferCollection.Clear();
        }

        // do something with the collection ...
    }

    public abstract void RequiredStuff(StuffCollection aTransferCollection);
}

public class ConcreteItem : BaseItem
{
    // ...

    public override void RequiredStuff(StuffCollection collector )
    {
        Stuff stuff;
        // ...
        collector.Add(stuff);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice idea, haven't thought of this!